# the code for retrieving an image url from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

hallo

I have a gridview with the image displayed in the gridview(the image was uploaded and the path posted to the database) and by setting the DataImageUrlField of the gridview to the field in the database that contains the image path I can display the picture.

What code can I use to retrieve this image path again from the gridview(so that I can store it in a session variable to display the same image on a different page)
or do i have to physically access the path again from the Database?

regards
A

Comment: Why not just bind that image to an image control on a different page?  You probably already have a way of getting it out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can get image control from that column and get ImageUrl from it.
like these codes:

```
Image img = (Image)gridView.Rows[1].Cells[1].Controls[1];
    string url = img.ImageUrl;
```

but you need to know rows and cell of image and also control index.